# Grails save(flash:true)

Tags: hibernate, grails

I inherited project in Grails 2.3.7 and found few occurences of:

```
domainInstance.save(flash:true)
```

I know about **flush** (to commit changes instantly), but can not find anything about **flash**. Project's compiling and working without any warning. What it does? Is it just spelling, and if so, why it isn't find and handled at compilation?

Comment: Maybe a typo? according to the [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) `save` does not have a parameter flash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use that type of method call, what that compiles down too is actually.

```
save(Map params)
```

So whether it's..

```
save(flush: true)
```

or

```
save(flash: true, danceOnTheSpot: false)
```

It doesn't matter. Groovy will pick the bits it wants and ignore the bits it doesn't. This is functionally equivalent to calling..

```
save()
```

Which makes it really powerful! One map with all the parameters for 50 method calls. Maintenance nightmare, but still pretty damn cool.

Comment: Right answer! hibernate just pics up what it want to from that map.

Answer (score 1):

For better or for worse, Groovy will compile many 'typos' like this one on a variable name. Similar to Perl (and some other scripting languages), you don't have to declare a variable, you can just type it as you use it. Cool for fast coding, but means that compilation won't catch many common errors.